# Loop structure skips some letters?

Tags: assembly

I have here a code that is supposed to:

- Take input
- Compare to each lower-case letter of the alphabet `"a"-"z"` / `97d-122d`

  - Compare if current character is equal input: if true, proceed to conversion and echo
  - Increment current character
  - Compare if counter is equal to limit, while not continue testing characters
- If not found from `a` - `z`, display invalid input message and go to input prompt

Here's my code:

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
    Prompt  db 10, 13, 10, 13, "Enter character: $"
    Upper   db 10, 13, "Upper Case: $"
    Invalid db 10, 13, "Invalid Character!$"

.code
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    mov cx, 26
input:
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, Prompt
    int 21h

    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h

        cmp al, ' '
        je exit

    mov bl, 0
    mov bh, 97d     ; bh == 'a'
tst:
        add bh, bl
        cmp al, bh  ; cmp (input,bl) 
        je continue ; if equal go to continue 
    add bl, 1
    cmp bl, 122     ; cmp (bh,'z')
    jne tst         ; if not equal loop

                    ; Invalid if not found from 'a' - 'z'
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, Invalid
    int 21h
    jmp input

continue:
    sub al, 32              ; Subtract 32 to make it Upper Case
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, Upper
    int 21h

    mov ah, 02h
    mov dl, al
    int 21h
    jmp input

exit:
    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h
end
```

But there are some letters that it considers invalid: `c`, `f`, `h`, `i`, `n`, `r`, `s`, `w`, `x`, `y`, `z` 
What causes these behaviours? 
*Info: I use tasm.exe as assembler, tlink.exe for linker and dos-box for emulator*

Comment: That's pretty old ASM :)

Answer (score 1):

To fix your problem you should change it to this:

```
    mov bl, 97
tst:
    cmp al, bl  ; cmp (input,bl) 
    je continue ; if equal go to continue 
    add bl, 1
    cmp bl, 123     ; cmp (bh,'z'+1 to include z as well)
    jne tst         ; if not equal loop
```

However, this code is rather ineffecient. You should take a look at the instructions `jg` and `jl`. Your loop is not really needed at all because you can do this with a cmparison.

Pseudocode:

```
if(ah < 'a')
   jmp invalid
if(ah > 'z')
   jmp invalid

printUpper
jmp continue
```

Also, if a value is intended as a character it makes the code more readbable to acutally use that character, instead of it's ASCII value. i.E. `move bl, 'a'`.

BTW: Exit on space is not according to your spec. :)

Answer (score 1):

If `bl` is the character then why are you comparing with `bh` and why are you adding `bl` to `bh`? Note that you don't need a loop for checking if a number is in some interval just check that it's greater-than-or-equal to the lower limit and less-than-or-equal to the upper limit.

PS: As usual, learn to use a debugger so you can fix your own mistakes.